# How to convert html template (with images) to pdf?

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, python-2.7, django-templates

I have been struggling with this for a few days now. I am trying to convert an html template in django to a pdf. I have got this part down using both reportlab and xhtml2pdf in seperate instances, but have not been able to get the images to convert with either option. With xhtml2pdf I keep getting the error 'Warning: needs a valid file name! the file name being a url such as /home/products/2312312

Please if you know how I can achieve this I would GREATLY appreciate your help!!

Comment: Please attach part of your template which is related to issue

Comment: @AlexandrTatarinov are you still finding a way to create a PDF with HTML which contain img?

Answer (score 0):

Something that might [help](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/xhtml2pdf/Vd4CCKN4qek).

- Make sure static/media urls are correct.
- Provide a url with valid extension.